# How can I get the list of flavor dimensions in build.gradle?

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-flavordimension

In my `build.gradle`, I have

```
android {
    flavorDimensions "first", "second"
    productFlavors {
        a {
            dimension "first"
        }
...
}
```

How can I get the list of `flavorDimensions` in the same order that gradle will use when creating the combinations of flavors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's available as an ArrayList from `android.flavorDimensionList`.

Comment: give examples..